# Testing if PowerShell script is being ran via Enter-PSSession?

Tags: powershell

I've got a PowerShell 2.0 script which performs some tasks involving non-MS apps which it launches. This works great if running via RDP or local console, but ends up deleting files when not intended if ran via an Enter-PSSession session from a remote workstation.

What I'm looking for and not finding (or comprehending), is if there is a way within a PowerShell script to test for if it is being executed locally, or remotely via Enter-PSSession. That would allow me to test if it was a remote session, and gracefully exit with a "Sorry, this must be ran locally" message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with the following:
`if ($Host.Name -like '*RemoteHost') { write-error "You must run locally"}`

But my real suggestion would be figure out why the script doesn't run over a PSRemoting session and fix that problem.

Comment: I'd also be far more worried about why a remote session deletes files.  What happens remotely could also happen locally.

Comment: The script does a delete, then a call on a 3rd party executable which writes out a new file. However, if same file exists, the 3rd party exe does not overwrite; something which I don't have control over. And for this script, the purpose of it is to overwrite existing. In all cases, the files being overwritten can be regenerated should an undesired delete occurs; its more of an annoyance than a catastrophe. I'm just trying to make the script a bit more polite in its behavior.

Comment: Jason's answer worked great. The only addition I added was to stick an "Exit 0" at the end so that remote users got a clean exit out of the script. "if ($Host.Name -like '*RemoteHost') { write-error "You must run locally"; Exit 0}"

Comment: makes enough sense, I just love to live by the idea of if it can be done locally It should be able to be done by Invoke-Command. It makes things simpler when you have tons of machines to manage.